# DNSSelector support in Kubernetes Network policy

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am trying to implement Kubernetes Network policy in my application on the basis of domain name to control the Egress and Ingress calls to the pod. I found [DNSSelector](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453) but it seems from there [last comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453#issuecomment-368334028) that this feature is not implemented in Kubernetes. 
I explored calico also, but in calico this feature comes under [calico-enterprise](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/calico-enterprise/egress-access-controls) hence it is paid. Can someone let me know if any other way out there to achieve this or maybe DNSSelector is being implemented now in Kubernetes?

Comment: Hello @solveit. Looks like a feature like this is still not implemented (nor being implemented) in k8s yet. Other sources are pointing towards that Calico solution that you have already mentioned. I am still looking for a possible solution but there is a possibility that it is exactly how you described it.

Comment: Thanks @WytrzymałyWiktor. How about Kubernetes DNS service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#introduction to control the egress calls ? With some dns server that I can integrate with k3s and use this service ?

Comment: Hello @solveit. That would be a topic for a separate question. Remember to follow [these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you wish to ask about it. As for your original question, I will post a community wiki answer for it in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

Unfortunately, the [DNSSelector](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453) is not yet implemented in Kubernetes (nor being implemented).

[Calico Enterprise](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/calico-enterprise/egress-access-controls) supports such functionality if you wish to pay for it.